# Why click event in backbone not working?

Tags: backbone.js, fancybox

```
     //I am using template in view

     App.Backbone.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        className: 'pp-entry group',
        template :_.template('<img src="i/pp-pic-8.png" class="pp-pic" alt="" />),
        templatedetails:_.template('`<div style="display:none"><div id="pp-details-<%=username%>" class="pp-details"><div class="cta clear"><input type="button" name="" value="Add to my Wallet" class="mar-right-10 addtowallet" /><input type="button" class="mar-right-10 addtogib" name="" value="Add to gib as link" /><input type="button" name="" value="Close" onclick="$.fancybox.close()" /></div></div><.div>'`)

        //Here is the click event defined

        events:{    
            "click .addtowallet":"addlinktowallet",
            "click .addtogib":"addasgiblink"
            },

       //Render contents

       render: function() { 
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        $(this.el).attr('id', 'pp-'+this.model.get('username')); //This is used to set the id for the "li" tag

        $('#pp-'+this.model.get('username')).append(this.templatedetails(this.model.toJSON())); //appending to the template
        },

        //But when i am defining the function the click event does not get triggered

        addasgiblink: function(){
            alert("gib button clicked");        
            },

        addlinktowallet: function(){
            alert("wallet button clicked");     
            }
});
```

The question is when i click on the pic as rendered from **template** a fancybox popup opens where **templatedetails** is rendered but when i click on the buttons in the popup it does not get triggered. Why the click function is not working?

The HTML that is generated after rendering is

```
<li id="pp-bikram" class="pp-entry group">
<img class="pp-pic" alt="" src="i/pp-pic-8.png">
<div style="display:none">
<div id="pp-details-bikram" class="pp-details">
<div class="cta clear">
<input class="mar-right-10 addtowallet" type="button" value="Add to my Wallet" name="">
<input class="mar-right-10 addtogib" type="button" value="Add to gib as link" name="">
<input type="button" onclick="$.fancybox.close()" value="Close" name="">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

Till this point everything is working fine but i am not getting why the click event is not not working. Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work because fancybox is not opening your content directly but its "clonning" it into its own container $('#fancybox-content').
Nice solution i think is possible by rebinding this container as Backbone.View.$el so you'll have Backbone.events{} working uppon that:

```
window.FancyboxView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        click: 'handleClick'
    },
    initialize:function () {
        this.$trigger = this.$el.find('a.trigger');
        this.$trigger.fancybox({
            onComplete:$.proxy(function () {
                this.setElement($('#fancybox-content')[0]);
            }, this)
        });
    },
    handleClick:function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            console.log('woala!')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code while executing this line

```
$('#pp-'+this.model.get('username'))
```

that element wont be available in the dom. So what you have to do is

```
$(this.el).append(this.templatedetails({// Your json}))
```

As per my observation both this.el and $('#pp-'+this.model.get('username')) are the same the li tag. So refer it as $(this.el). Please let me know if it works

Comment: if i remove the fancybox than it is click event working , how can we make it working with fancybox

Comment: can you add a class to fancybox button and add the click event of the fancybox button in the events hash along with .addtowallet , .addtogib. Also remove the inline onclick handler of the fancybox button.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the code as below.

```
events:{
            "click .addtowallet":"addlinktowallet",
            "click .addtogib":"addasgiblink"
            "click .fancybox":"fancyBoxClose"
        },

        fancyBoxClose : function(){
            $.fancybox.close()
        }

templatedetails:_.template('`<div style="display:none"><div id="pp-details-<%=username%>" class="pp-details"><div class="cta clear"><input type="button" name="" value="Add to my Wallet" class="mar-right-10 addtowallet" /><input type="button" class="mar-right-10 addtogib" name="" value="Add to gib as link" /><input type="button" name="" value="Close" class="fancybox" /></div></div><.div>'`)
```